# Why can't I find a camera in my new Win10 installation on Aspire SW3-016?

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire, camera

I tried looking for it in Device Manager. None.
I tried opening Camera app, response is
"Something went wrong. Make sure your camera is connected and not being used by another app."
My aspire switch contains two cams, one in front and other rear but not one of them is detected in my win10 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used Drivers Pack Solution Offline in installing drivers to the notebook and that pack is located on my flash drive. While installing the Intel Camera Driver (Drivers Pack Solution shows this as a chipset installation), it prompted me to restart the device to complete the installation. However, I removed the flash drive while it was performing the restart and there started the endless loop of "Performing Automatic Repair" and "Diagnosing ...".

I tried to reset the device about 5 times with the same result everytime I restart it. So, I did another win10 installation using an image in a drive, installed the drivers again using Drivers Pack Solution and this time did not remove the flash drive while installing the chipset driver (Intel Camera). It's all okay now, camera's working, no more performing automatic repair and diagnosing something error.

Answer (score 0):

From [Acer Support center](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42125#_ga=2.53615464.1151609900.1502303005-105527334.1502303005), Windows 10 update in November 2015 caused users to experience problems using their camera. Updating Windows will help in this case. Or you can follow the given instruction:

> Visit the [Drivers and
>   Manuals](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) section of the
>   Acer support website.
>   Enter your Serial Number/SNID or search for
>   your product by Model.
>   Select the Patch tab.
>   Click the Download
>   link for the file you want to download. [(Fix camera function fail
>   after upgrade to Win10 TH2)](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Patch/Patch/Patch_Acer_20160506_W10x86_A.zip?acerid=636001971830724791&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE%20SWITCH%2010&Step3=SW5-011&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6)
>   Unzip the downloaded file and follow the
>   instructions in the file named How to update ISP driver.pdf.

In case patch not showing direct [download link](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Patch/Patch/Patch_Acer_20160506_W10x86_A.zip?acerid=636001971830724791&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE%20SWITCH%2010&Step3=SW5-011&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6).

Other Sources: [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17444/windows-camera-app-webcams-help), [drivereasy](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fixing-we-cant-find-your-camera-error-code-0xa00f4244/)

Comment: Where's the patch tab here https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6460?b=1&pn=NT.G8ZSP.002 ?

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Added a download link to that file.